# ios table data not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS programming

I am facing problem to view table data on my iOS device but it can be seen on console
Below is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var model = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webService.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
     let str = ""

    webService.fireRequest(functionName: "ClassName.php", requestString: str, view: view)

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return model.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "classWiseMgmtTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = model[indexPath.row]
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "divisionWiseTableViewCell") as! DivisionWiseViewController
    vc.term = self.model[indexPath.section]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)



}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

//    func webserviceDidFinishWith(response: [String : Any]) {
//    }

func webserviceDidFinishWith(response: [String : Any], functionName: String) {

    print("Response\(response)")


    let array = response["Cls_Name"] as? [[String:String]]

    if array != nil
    {
        self.model.removeAll()

        for obj in array!
        {
            self.model.append(obj["Cls_Name"]!)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }


}

}
```

Comment: Quick Question Why you are using sections instead of rows ? . Your code doesn't seems to be suitable for section table. You can use `numberOfRowsInSection` instead of `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: You are mixing up `section` and `row`

Comment: @RB1509 How do you know that an extra nib is used?

Comment: @vadian if he or she has customcell in used than it should require i think

Comment: @RB1509 No, it is not required. Since Xcode 6(!) you can design multiple (custom) cells as prototype cells directly in the table view in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks @vadian for update my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model.count;
}
```

I guess the issue is with the rows in the tableView

and also i am not sure if you are having this much number of sections.? If there is only one section pass like this

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

also check this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cellIdentifier : String = "classWiseMgmtTableViewCell";
        var cell : SportCell! = 
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! SportCell //Pass your tableViewCell FileName here

    }
```

Hope this Helps.

### Edit to set  Data as per your response

you can extract data like:

```
  var arrResponse = repsonse as! [String:Any] //Instead of response pass your WebService Response here
    
    let arrClassName = arrResponse["clsname"] as! NSArray
    
    print(arrClassName)
```

### Edit Demo Link Integrated with WS Call

**Link to google drive is:**  [Demo Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fIGhTwVqxHjuqSix-l9u9NRRf6Mu926U/view?usp=sharing)

**Some Notes:** I have used Alamofire for Get Method, and also in case the project does not run or fail to detect the Alamofire, just install the pod again using `pod install` and it will work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @juee Edited the answer and Added a demo project for you with working code. If it helps do approve the answer

Comment: thanks a lot ....its perfectly working fine now....thank u once again ... thank u so much..

Comment: @juee Pleasure helping you buddy, it would be really appreciated if you approve my answer, by ticking the tick with green.

Answer (score 0):

Update inside `cellForRowAt` function with below code

```
cell.textLabel?.text = model[indexPath.section]
```

Comment: Though you are partially right, but if only that was the case, atleast the first element would have been always displayed. But it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One thing missing and one thing wrong.

Missing (put this in `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "classWiseMgmtTableViewCell")
```

Wrong (Replace `indexPath.row` by `indexPath.section` in `cellForRowAt`):

```
cell.textLabel?.text = model[indexPath.section]
```

Comment: How do you know that the cell is **not** designed as prototype cell in Interface Builder? If it is you must not register the cell.

Comment: @vadian : Because as per OP's code, in the line **tableView.dequeueReusableCell**, he hasn't type cased the cell as a custom cell.

Comment: He could just use a standard `UITableViewCell`, this is quite likely since no custom outlets are used (`textLabel` is standard)

Comment: @vadian : Exactly. I think the identifier is named as if it is a custom cell, but it is not.